# Python tweepy: Tweets only after bot starts

Tags: python, time, twitter, tweepy

I want to write bot that searches for tweets after the bot starts. If the tweet has been tweeted before the bot starts working, the bot should ignore it. I have this code right now:

I am using **Python** and **tweepy**.

```py
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline,
        since_id=since_id).items():
        new_since_id = max(tweet.id, new_since_id)
```

I don't know how to implement it, I thought about use time function and compare it with the time right now, but I don't know hot to get the time of the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's API doesn't allow for searching for tweets by time. You would have to compare the tweet's `created_at` attribute to the time at which your bot started.